# How to search the letter in php codeigniter autocomplete

Tags: php, codeigniter

using autocomplete option in my php codeigniter project. It filter based in the first letter from database. Now i want to search wherever that letter present in that column.

using the code for get the data from the database like 
Ajax

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(function() {
        $( "#category" ).autocomplete({
            source: function(request, response) {
                $.ajax({ url: base_url+"/suggest/get_category",
                data: { term: $("#category").val()},
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                success: function(data){
                    response(data);
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 2
        });
    });
```

Controller

```
function get_category()
{
    $term = $this->input->post('term');

    if (strlen($term) < 2) break;

    $rows = $this->suggest->GetAutocomplete(array('keyword' => $term));

    $json_array = array();
    foreach ($rows as $row)
         array_push($json_array, $row->category_name);

    echo json_encode($json_array);
}
```

Model

```
function GetAutocomplete($options = array())
    {
        $this->db->select('category_name');
        $this->db->like('category_name', $options['keyword'], 'after');
        $query = $this->db->get('category');
        return $query->result();
    }
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: How can you pass array in parameter?? You must need Ajax for autocomplet input or suggestion input.

Comment: i'm using ajax for input value, I'm using this code in Models for getting the result from database

Comment: Please paste ajax function here. so it is easy to understand ..

Comment: ajax function is updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For late, You may change in $this->db->like() because you have passed parameter 'after' so You need to replace third paramenter with 'both' keyword,

As per CI-Active Record documentation, 
If you want to control where the wildcard (%) is placed, you can use an optional third argument. Your options are 'before', 'after' and 'both' (which is the default).

```
$this->db->like('title', 'match', 'before'); 
// Produces: WHERE title LIKE '%match'  

$this->db->like('title', 'match', 'after'); 
// Produces: WHERE title LIKE 'match%' 

$this->db->like('title', 'match', 'both'); 
// Produces: WHERE title LIKE '%match%'
```

For more details you may visit http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html

```
function GetAutocomplete($options = array())
{
    $this->db->select('category_name');
    $this->db->like('category_name', $options['keyword'], 'both');
    $query = $this->db->get('category');
    return $query->result();
}
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

```
    $options=$this->input->get('term');     
    $this->db->like('category_name',$options);          
    $query=$this->db->get('category');
    $result=$query->result();
    $names=array();
    foreach($result as $row)
    {
        $val=array();
        $val['label']=$row->category_name;
        $val['value']=$row->category_name;
        array_push($names,$val);
    }
    echo json_encode($names);
```

Comment: i try this code but result will be same, it search from starts only

Answer (score -1):

Please try this:

Its works for me ..

Hopefully it will work for you as well.

http://www.jamipietila.fi/codeigniter-and-autocomplete-with-jquery/

http://vortexdev.netii.net/article_16/How_to:_Autocomplete_with_CodeIgniter_and_jQuery

Other links i tried :

http://codeigniterlover.blogspot.in/2013/01/jquery-autocomplete-in-codeigniter-php.html

http://www.codersmount.com/2012/09/jquery-ui-autocomplete-in-codeigniter-with-database/

Comment: Why are you loading view ?

Comment: http://vortexdev.netii.net/article_16/How_to:_Autocomplete_with_CodeIgniter_and_jQuery Here i suggested the questioner to followed this site.

Comment: Actually i try autocomplete option from this link http://www.jamipietila.fi/codeigniter-and-autocomplete-with-jquery/ , it's working fine. But it search whatever is starts like the typed content. I need to search the whole content not only starts